# Python/Twisted - Server also a client?

Tags: python, networking, twisted

Basically, I have a twisted server accepting data from clients, which works great. What I'd like this server to do is send certain received data to another server, which will then echo it to everything connected to it(essentially sharing data between multiple servers using a central hub.) So as a simple idea:

Data -> Server1 -> Central Server -> Connected clients(Server1, Server2, Server3, etc;)

Any ideas on how this could be achieved? I've been told calling

```
reactor.connect(host, port)
```

inside the server function will create a client, but how can I share the data between the server and the client? Is there a way to call the clients sendLine from within the servers dataReceived?

Comment: Twisted is neither a server nor a client per se; it is simply an event loop.

Answer (score 0):

Look how proxies are implemented in Twisted.